# Don't understand odd C function definition

Tags: c, arrays

I am maintaining a large block of C code and attempting to improve it and I have run across a function which uses a syntax unfamiliar to me:

```
char (*(lgLinkStrs)())[CONFIG_MAX_STRING] {
...
}
```

I know that it returns a 2-dim array of chars (basically an array of strings) which was defined as a global variable elsewhere and that this isn't a best practice. I'm familiar with the common methods of passing in and returning arrays as pointers.

I don't understand this syntax and I can't even figure out what to google. And I can't improve the code until I understand it.

Could someone explain to me what this syntax means or at least where I can look it up?

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html .

Comment: Google function pointers

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/)

Comment: @EdHeal it's actually declaring a function returning a pointer to an array. So OP, google pointers to arrays

Comment: Note that using cdecl you need to replace `CONFIG_MAX_STRING` with an int literal.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good candidate for improvement. Good luck fighting the good fight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that postfix `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so

```
T *a[N];    // a is an array of pointers to T
T (*a)[N];  // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();     // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();   // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Thus:

```
        lgLinkStrs                          -- lgLinkStrs
       (lgLinkStrs)                         -- surrounded by superfluous parentheses
       (lgLinkStrs)()                       -- is a function taking no arguments
      *(lgLinkStrs)()                       -- returning a pointer to
     (*(lgLinkStrs)())[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]   -- an array of
char (*(lgLinkStrs)())[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]   -- char
```

Another approach is to work from the outside in - you understand `char`, and you understand `[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]`, collapse everything else to something simple:

```
char x[CONFIG_MAX_STRING];
```

Thus, `x` is a `CONFIG_MAX_STRING`-size array of `char`.  Now expand `x` one step:

```
char   x [CONFIG_MAX_STRING]
     +-++
     |  |
     V  V
char (*u)[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]
```

Thus, `u` is a pointer to an array of `char`.  We used `*u` instead of `u()` since `()` has higher precedence, and thus binds more tightly to the expression than `*`.  Now expand `u`:

```
char (*     u      )[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]
       +----+-----+
       |          |
       V          V
char (*lgLinkStrs())[CONFIG_MAX_STRING]
```

Thus, `lgLinkStrs` is a function returning a pointer to an array of `char`.  Obviously, the extra parentheses surrounding `lgLinkStrs` in the original declaration are superfluous.

**Edit**

Some commenters have mentioned the "spiral rule", which isn't a rule *per se*, but falls out of the precedence rules I mentioned above:

```
  +---------------+
  |   +--------+  |
  |   | +----+ |  |
  |   | |    | |  |
char  ( * f () )[N];
      | | |  | |  |
      | | +--+ |  |
      | +------+  |
      +-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`lgLinkStrs` is a function returning a pointer to an array of `CONFIG_MAX_STRING` `char` and you are defining the function here. The curly braces denote the body of the function.

Also follow the spiral rule here - you will easily get to the declaration.